# If $f'(0)$ does not necessarily exists, can $f'_+(0)$ be defined as $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n\left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(0)\right]$?

Tags: derivatives

Some book says that:

> If $f'(0)$ does not necessarily exists, then
>    $f'_+(0)=\lim\limits_{n\to
>  \infty}n\left[f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)-f(0)\right](n \in
>  \mathbb{N})$ does not **hold** necessarily.

I'm confused about that. Is it true?

Comment: Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin(2\pi / x) & \text{if }x \neq 0 \\0 & \text{if }x = 0 \\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Bungo $f'_+(0)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0+}x\dfrac{\sin(2\pi/x)-0}{2\pi}=0.$

Comment: @mengdie1982: Your calculation is incorrect. Your $x$ that multiplies $\sin\left(2\pi/x\right)$ should instead divide it. That is, your limit in the original post is essentially $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}.$$ Your calculation in the previous comment mistakenly multiplies by $x$.

Comment: But then as $x \to 0^+,$ $2\pi/x \to \infty$ so the sine term on top oscillates in $[-1,1]$ (no limit) As Clayton notes you can't move $x$ to numerator.

Comment: @mengdie1982 $f'_+(0)$ does not exist, since for $x =1/(n+1/4)$, $( f(x)- f(0) )/x= (n+1/4) \sin(2n\pi+\pi/2) - (n+1/4) \cdot 0 = n+1/4 \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, while for $x = 1/n$, $(f(x)-f(0))/x = 0$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks! I get it all,

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/q, &x = p/q \quad [p\in \mathbb Z^\times, q\in \Bbb N^*, \gcd(p,q)=1],\\
0, & x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \bigcup\{0\},
\end{cases}
$$
Then clearly 
$$
 \frac {f(1/n)- f(0)} {1/n} = 1,
$$
but actually $f$ is not right-handed differentiable at $0$ thus not differentiable at $0$, since when $ x >0$,
$$
\frac {f(x) - f(0)}x = 
\begin{cases}
1, & x \in \mathbb Q^+\\
0, & x \in \mathbb R^+ \setminus \mathbb Q,
\end{cases}
$$
and the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac {f(x)- f(0)}x 
$$
does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

## My View

Thanks for your enlightment. I have an idea for the problem, now.

Consider the function$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{x},& x\neq 0;\\0,&x =0. \end{cases}$$

We may verify that $f(x)$ is continous at $x=0$, but it has not derivative even single-side derivative there. Since
$$\frac{f(0+\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=\sin\frac{2\pi}{\Delta x},\tag 1$$when$\Delta x \to \pm 0$, $(1)$ tends to no limit. But if we take $\Delta x=\dfrac{1}{n},n \in \mathbb{N},$ we have$$\frac{f(0+\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=\sin 2n\pi\equiv 0,\tag 2$$when $n \to \infty$,$(2)$ has a limit $0$.

Obviously,$(1)$ and $(2)$ contradicts each other. We want to ask the reason why the contradition comes out. In fact, according to **Heine theorem**, to change the variable $x \to a$ into some sequence $x_n \to a$ in the limit expression is conditional. The conditon is just that $\lim\limits_{x \to a}$ exists. If $\lim\limits_{x \to a}$ does not exist, you can't change it into $\lim\limits_{x_n \to a}$, which is the reason.